# Retreive data with hasOne in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, has-one

I would like to know how to retreive data with hasOne in laravel?
For example, I have a brand table and a product table that has a column that contains the brand's id, so if a product should have a brand "hasOne" works perfectly with the relationship of the two tables, but how do I do if a product does not necessarily have a brand, then when adding the product the id of the brand stored in database is 0 and when I make a request on this line, laravel gives me an error.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: In the migration file for the `product` table, make sure the `brand_id` column has `nullable()` added to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the product has no brand, instead of adding 0, enter `NULL` to the database.
You will need to change the database and add `->nullable()` to the `brand_id` column

Also, it seems like a `Product` should `belongTo` a `Brand` instead of `hasOne`

Your `Product` model should look like:

```
class Product extends Model {

    public function brand() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }
}
```

And your `Brand`

```
class Brand extends Model {

    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
if($product->brand) {
    // product has brand
}
else {
    // product does not have brand
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have found the solution : i have forgot to test if the product has a brand before rendering it to the blade.